# gnuplot-cpp cannot feed command to pipe

Tags: c++, pipe, gnuplot

I'm using gnuplot-cpp to draw math graphs using C++. As I vaguely understand, this is an interface which feeds command to pgnuplot.exe and shows the output in another GUI.

So far, I've got the error like:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command...
```

the original command of which fed to the pipe is:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin/pgnuplot.exe"
```

the same command executed in _access(cmd) returns TRUE for the existence of the executable whereas it returns the error described priorily when executed in _popen(cmd,"w");

I'm wondering the error comes from the cmd string format and I've tried "/", "\", "\\"... but nothing works

the 2 code files are [gnuplot_i.hpp](http://pastebin.com/VJiPrB2q) and [example.cc](http://pastebin.com/epEDrcib)

Thank you in advance for any help!

Edit 01:

I've updated the two code files. They contain some of my supplementary edits

Comment: Could you show some code?

Comment: That's not gnuplot-iostream, but [gnuplot-cpp](http://code.google.com/p/gnuplot-cpp/). Have you tried escaping the spaces? `Gnuplot::set_GNUPlotPath("C:/Program\ Files\ (x86)/gnuplot/bin");`

Comment: @Christoph: I tried already, didn't work. As I mentioned, one works on _access(cmd) should also work on _popen(cmd). but not in my case

Comment: I've seen, that this is filed as bug: [Blanks in gnuplot path cause failure](https://code.google.com/p/gnuplot-cpp/issues/detail?id=9). But apparently that was not fixed. As workaround you may try to add the directory to your `PATH` and call ony `pgnuplot.exe`.

Comment: @Christoph: thank you!! I've been able to fix it. This is a good lesson for me to follow the development group's message board. Please make it an answer sothat this question can be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug of [`gnuplot-cpp`](http://code.google.com/p/gnuplot-cpp/), see the issue [Blanks in gnuplot path cause failure](https://code.google.com/p/gnuplot-cpp/issues/detail?id=9).

As workaround you can add the gnuplot directory to your `PATH` and call only `pgnuplot.exe`.