# gnuplot.exe path not found for writing in c++

Tags: c++, gnuplot

I'm new to gnuplot and was trying to just make a plot of random numbers to visualize the distribution of the psuedo-random `rand()` function in c++. However, I came across a problem that appears common: the path was not found for gnuplot.exe.

Possible relevant information before I go on:

Running Windows 10 64-bit. Compiler: CLion. gnuplot.exe path: `C:\Program Files (x86)\gnuplot\bin` I have the latest version of gnuplot form [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuplot/) (as of 10/21/19: 5.2.7 I believe).

I have already checked these questions:

[gnuplot-cpp cannot feed command to pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20135849/gnuplot-cpp-cannot-feed-command-to-pipe)

[Gnuplot & C++: Can't find gnuplot neither in PATH nor in "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39390303/gnuplot-c-cant-find-gnuplot-neither-in-path-nor-in)

I've looked through many other questions but they weren't as relevant to the problem I have. I tried implementing the answers there and did not make any progress. I have the same [gnuplot_i.hpp](https://pastebin.com/VJiPrB2q) file and changed the problem line to:

```
#if defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__TOS_WIN__)
std::string Gnuplot::m_sGNUPlotFileName = "gnuplot.exe";
std::string Gnuplot::m_sGNUPlotPath = "C:/Program_Files(x86)/gnuplot/bin/";
```

I also have the correct `PATH` set for gnuplot as a environmental variable and can execute `gnuplot` from cmd.

The errors I've gotten were:

```
Cannot find gnuplot neither in PATH nor in "C:/Program_Files(x86)/gnuplot/bin"
```

and, when I removed the "_" from the path above and replaced it with a space:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

This last one is the only one that appears now, even though I do not have the space anymore, as it's been mentioned that having spaces in the path is a known bug with gnuplot. I am aware that `Program_Files(x86)` is not a real path, I was just trying to get rid of the second error message.

My main.cpp, if it even matters:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gnuplot_i.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    try {
        Gnuplot rand_plot("lines");
    }
    catch (GnuplotException ge) {
        cout << ge.what() << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any help on solving these errors would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Problem might be missing quotes when launching the program, so it splits by spaces. Simple workaround/test: install gnuplot to directory with no spaces...

Comment: Change line 1714-1715 to `std::string tmp = std::string("\"") + Gnuplot::m_sGNUPlotPath + "/" + Gnuplot::m_sGNUPlotFileName + std::string("\"");` That way the `popen` call below it will be able to correctly start the program.

Comment: Thank you both for helping. I found Botje's answer to work so I went with it as I don't have to reinstall and move things around. I'll add an answer. Again, thank you. You wouldn't believe how many hours I wasted looking for an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Botje in the comments solved the issue. Changing lines 1714-1715 in `gnuplot_i.h` to `std::string tmp = std::string("\"") + Gnuplot::m_sGNUPlotPath + "/" + Gnuplot::m_sGNUPlotFileName + std::string("\"");` fixed the problem.